# How much should I cut off my Dachshund's nails?

Tags: dogs, safety, grooming

My 3 year old Dachshund has long nails and they click when she walks. How much can I clip off safely and how often should I?

Comment: It is perfectly normal that a dogs nails click on the ground with each step. In fact, it would be unhealthy and painful to clip the nails so short they don't click while walking. Please see if this post answers your question: [Why do I need to clip my dog's nails](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/7165/12501). If not, please [edit] your question and explain how your problem differs from the one in the linked question.